# Middle aged man travels through portal to a Greek speaking world?

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find the name of this book I've read 25-30 years ago.

I think it was a Roger Zelazny book, but could be well off the mark as I wasn't able to find a description that tallies with my recollection of the plot.

It starts with a middle aged man who through some emergency ends up going through a portal - this world seems to speak an ancient Greek dialect (which he just so happens to have been an expert in on Earth, having taught Greek). This man has had amnesia and only recalls stuff from around his twenties onwards.

In this world, which is built in layers - like a pyramid, he becomes young and healthy (back to his mid twenties form) and starts climbing up towards the palace of the (missing) ruler of this universe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s by Philip Jose Farmer, not Roger Zelazny. It’s his [World Of Tiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tiers) series, of which the first volume is *The Maker of Universes*.

> The story follows Robert Wolff, a man disenchanted with his life and
>   his marriage. One day, while looking at a new house, Wolff discovers a
>   strange horn in the basement. Blowing the horn, Wolff is transported
>   to a strange new world, the World of Tiers. Wolff finds himself
>   initially in an edenic paradise known as Okeanos. This region is the
>   first level of the planet, which contains a number of tiers like a
>   wedding cake, separated by vast mountain ranges. The entire planet is
>   ruled over by a cruel and mysterious lord named Jadawin, who created
>   it. Okeanos consists of a beach, an ocean, and a small forest and is
>   populated by nymph like humans who originated in and near ancient
>   Greece. In this new world, Wolff regains his youth and vigor and falls
>   in love with a local woman named Chryseis who lived in Troy at the
>   time of the Trojan War.

Be warned that as with other series by Farmer, the more recent books are not as good and the series does not have a satisfactory conclusion.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it... was fixated with Zelazny (must have been reading a lot of his stuff around the same time).

Comment: As noted in a comment on the linked duplicate question, Zelazny acknowledged this series as an influence on Amber.

Comment: I’d like to mention to avoid any after the first five books. The one I think is most recent, Red Orc’s Rage, has one of the worst opening sentences in literature and only goes down from there.